# What happens when you go outside "short" range?

Tags: java, range, short

What happens when you go "outside" the short range? Here is a little question.

```
        int ia = 32767;
        int ib = 32768;
        short sa = (short)ia;
        short sb = (short)ib;

        System.out.println(sa);
        System.out.println(sb);
```

Why will sa print out 32767 and sb -32768?? I don't understand this..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11990681/overflowing-short-in-java

Answer (score 2):

You just go from

```
Short.MAX_VALUE --> 32767
```

to

```
Short.MIN_VALUE --> -32768
```

`short` is 16-bit signed primitive data type.

32767 in 16-bit binary is

```
0111_1111_1111_1111
```

by adding one you just go to

```
1000_0000_0000_0000
```

corresponding to -32768. Note as

```
System.out.println(Short.MIN_VALUE);
System.out.println((short)(1+Short.MAX_VALUE));
```

both output the same value

```
-32768
-32768
```

Comment: wow thanks for fast help! Just got it now! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `short`maximum value is  `(2^15)-1 = 32767`. Whe  you try to assign a bigger number, it overflows, assuming it's minimum that is `-2^15 = -32768`

There is also `underflow`concept, where you try to assign a lower value that the minimum defined for that type of variable, in this case it will assume the highest value instead, you can try and assigning a `short = -32769` and see what it will print.

You can check the `[short][1]`documentation for further readings.

Comment: wow thanks for fast help! Just got it now! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

All of the types `byte`, `short`, `char`, `int`, `long` have a set range of possible values. These types wrap round so when you add one to the largest possible value, you get the smallest.

The largest `short` value is `32767` so when you try to represent `32768` you get the smallest `short` value instead.

Comment: wow thanks for fast help! Just got it now! Thanks!

Comment: No worries. II never use short anyway, so it's only with `byte` you really have to be worry about this stuff most of the time.