# Casting of byte data type

Tags: java, byte

Please explain how below code is working, as we know byte data type in java allows a range from -128 to 127.

My code snippet is:

```
public class DataTypes {

public static void main(String args[]){
byte b = (byte)140;
System.out.println(b);
   }
}
```

Output: -116

Comment: This is because of overflow

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Overflowing Short in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11990681/overflowing-short-in-java)

Comment: Check this wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow. The logic is the same for bytes, shorts, etc.

Answer (score 0):

A Byte will have 8 bits in its memory space. Using this space it can hold 256 values. This will span from -128 to 127 including 0. To support this spanning, a Byte value will be represented in binary format using [two's compliment method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement). The MSB (**M**ost **S**ignificant **B**it) will determine the sign (`0` - positive & `1` - negative) of the value.

If we consider the case of `140`, it will be clear if we represent `140` in binary format which is `1000 1100`. Remember the MSB will determine the sign and a `1` means the number is a negative value and `0` means it's a positive value. In this case we have a `1` making it a negative number.

If we apply reverse process to this two's compliment, we will first get `0111 0011` by inverting all the `1`s to `0`s and `0`s to `1`s. Then by adding 1, we get `0111 0100` which is equal to `116` in decimal format. But the MSB said it's a negative value, hence `-116`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help explain. The uppermost bit determines the 'sign'(positive or negative) of a variable.  Since Java does not have an explicit 'unsigned' integer form the best you can do is apply a 'bitwise' operation to the item in advance of displaying it force it to be considered 'unsigned'...or you can display it using it's hex format which is inherently unsigned.

```
public class DataTypes {

   public static void main(String args[]){
      byte b = (byte)140;
      System.out.println("hex value = "+String.format("0x%02X",b)+"\n");
      System.out.println("dec value = "+String.format("%d",(b & 0xff))+"\n");
   }
}
```

and a result of

```
hex value = 0x8C

dec value = 140
```

Answer (score 0):

140 is a `int`. It is converted to a `byte`, according to the [Java Language Specification, section 5.1.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3), as follows:

> A narrowing conversion of a signed integer to an integral type T simply discards all but the n lowest order bits

The lowest 8 bits of the `int` with value 140 are 10001100, which is the correct value for the byte, but which is negative since its highest bit, the sign bit, is 1.

Answer (score 0):

I think, when you cast the integer (140) to byte, the integer value converted into unsigned byte then b variable value is converted into signed byte. The number 140 considered as unsigned value because the number has not sign value indicator (+ or -)

Note about unsigned byte (the right value is representation (in file byte(s)) of left value):
0-127 = 0-127
(-128) - (-1) = 128 - 255