# How type extension occurs in case of positives and negatives in Java?

Tags: java, types, type-conversion

Is there any difference between how type conversion happens in case of positive and negative numbers?

For example, if we have

```
short a = 100;
```

and put it to

```
int b = a;
```

if we change '100' to '-100', does it make any difference?
I tried to find it compiling in IDEA, but didn't find difference, but I have this questions from my mentor.

Comment: There's nothing more authoritative than [the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-5.html). Your mentor probably wants you to find an answer yourself, in the materials he/she has already had you use, or there, or similar.

Comment: Not exactly the same as what you're asking, but this question has some good information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11990681/overflowing-short-in-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Disclaimer***: Since this is a homework question, what I say here might not be the "expected" answer.

There are two conversions involved here. The first one is a narrowing primitive conversion from `int` (the literal `100` evaluates to a value of type `int`) to `short`. The second one is a widening primitive conversion from `short` to `int`.

The second conversion will never lose information, as per the JLS [§5.1.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2):

> A widening primitive conversion does not lose information about the
>   overall magnitude of a numeric value in the following cases, where the
>   numeric value is preserved exactly:
>
> - ***from an integral type to another integral type***
> - from byte, short, or char to a floating point type
> - from int to double
> - from float to double in a strictfp expression (§15.4)

The first conversion is done like this, according to the JLS [§5.1.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3)

> A narrowing conversion of a signed integer to an integral type T
>   simply discards all but the n lowest order bits, where n is the number
>   of bits used to represent type T. In addition to a possible loss of
>   information about the magnitude of the numeric value, this may cause
>   the sign of the resulting value to differ from the sign of the input
>   value.

Both `-100` and `100` is representable with `short`, whose range is -65536...65535, so no information is lost here either.

In short, it doesn't matter whether you use `100` or `-100`, the result will be that `b` will store the value of `100` or `-100` respectively.